filtered special Database statements for google index
I have the url() statement in my database. all in www.site.com/random_alias format (splash pages).
Some links were created by the admin (userid=1) and archived to specialized (archived=1).
how can I tell Google to index URLs (just created by admin and archived) ? no index and follow for all other URLs. I have below code using php, but the filter condition doesn't work. and all pages turn to the index
<?php

foreach (\Core\DB::url()->where('userid', '1')
->where('archived', '1'))


    if ($url['userid'] == 1 && $url['Archived'] == 1) {

        echo '<meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>';
    } else {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>'; 
    }

endforeach; 

?>

also i use this query to select
SELECT userid, archived FROM psiturl WHERE userid = 1 AND archived='1'

a correct php code to filter URLS for index and no index tags condition.

Not sure what sense you thought it could make to output these meta tags in a loop? Unless your query were to only return one single record, you'd be creating multiple of these robots meta tags within one and the same document.

To say that in another way, in the header of your page template you should look up the current URL/page in your database an emit a single <meta name="robots"> tag corresponding to your logic. Alternatively to could also generate a robots.txt file that has no index settings for certain URLs, although that is a more passive way of doing it.
